# How to run standalone java with RabbitMQ and nodejs

Tags: java, node.js, rabbitmq, amqp

I've been working on putting node.js in front of our java webserver to take advantage of node's async handling - doing some light processing and other tasks and eventually socket.io. Most of the actual work of the app is done in java, and up until now, we've been using a jetty webserver to handle all requests. I had been initially considering using node-http-proxy to just forward (possibly modified requests). Upon further consideration, I realized that instead of forwarding the http request, I could instead use something like RabbitMQ and the node-amqp library for a more robust communication protocol. This would also enable better support for push from java through node and socket.io back to the browser.

My question is: now that handle all incoming requests with node, is there any reason to keep running java inside of jetty? If not, should I literally just run the java code from a main method on the command line? And finally, are there any major flaws to this approach?

Our application is a single page application, and beyond the first request to load up the page initially, all further calls are just restful json calls, and should be easy to transfer over amqp.

Comment: Why can't you just use multiple threads in Java?  What are you hoping to gain from adding all of the extra complexity of a message broker, and code in another language?

Comment: Without going into too much depth for the *why*, most of what we want to gain is the benefits of handling requests asynchronously, specifically holding onto requests cheaply (socket.io/throttling). We explored jetty continuations but the java code is pretty reliant on threads. For now, this seems cleaner despite complexity. We were also planning on taking advantage of AMQP in other areas.

Answer (score 2):

According to the usage, there is no advantage of using Jetty or Tomcat as the java program container. Jetty or Tomcat has advantage of receiving the HTTP request and forward it to the worker java program. But in your case, the request is received by NodeJS and forward to MQ, **the java worker will actively connect to MQ and get the task and send the result when done**. So it is better use standalone Java here. And it is easy to start many standalone Java program as workers cluster to deal more tasks when the request become lots. NodeJS and MQ can cache multi requests async and the Java workers can handler them sync. For example: 1 NodeJS server, 1 MQ server, 3 Java worker servers.

Comment: Since I'm used to using a container (unless I'm writing a small utility, or just running locally), what is the best way to set up these java workers to be robust, handling errors without completely crashing etc. I can obviously wrap at the top level with a try catch of anything and dumping to logs, but it seems like there should be something better.